# "base64 decoding error: Incorrect padding" when loading PuTTY/ppk private key to Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys, ssh-tunnel

I am attempting to create an SSH tunnel using `paramiko` and `SSHTunnelForwarder` using `Python 3.6` on Windows 10

I already have a connection setup with PuTTY and it connects without issue..

Whenever I try and start a connection with `paramiko` I get the following error:

> paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: base64 decoding error: Incorrect padding

I have attempted to pad the RSA key using `=` and `==` `===`... both at the beginning and the end (in the example 1 x `=` is at the end and it `%4 == 0`..

I have also tried passing in a `pem` file and a `ppk` version.

How can I make paramiko accept the key??

```
import paramiko
from io import StringIO

KEY = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"""

private_key_file = StringIO()
private_key_file.write(KEY)
private_key_file.seek(0)

print('\n\nlen(KEY)%4 ==', len(KEY)%4)
print()

mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(private_key_file)
```

Full traceback:

```
len(KEY)%4 == 0

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\pkey.py", line 306, in _read_private_key
data = decodebytes(b(''.join(lines[start:end])))
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\base64.py", line 553, in decodebytes
return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:/GIT/Production_apps/deploy_data_files/connect_tosql.py", line 37, in <module>
mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(private_key_file)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\pkey.py", line 227, in from_private_key
key = cls(file_obj=file_obj, password=password)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\rsakey.py", line 45, in __init__
self._from_private_key(file_obj, password)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\rsakey.py", line 173, in _from_private_key
data = self._read_private_key('RSA', file_obj, password)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\paramiko\pkey.py", line 308, in _read_private_key
raise SSHException('base64 decoding error: ' + str(e))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: base64 decoding error: Incorrect padding
```

(I have changed some random bytes in the key for security reasons but the length and error are the same)

This is the `ppk` file I use with PuTTY:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: user_1@computer
Public-Lines: 6
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAnQQd2g519EiUb+4dH8XDDagBWq/3lpFWD5Ng
TJlEnGAwhRsshtYPMvV5PXgJ6SMstRz4+/73nvJqe2SIHzBBNQeTsqQLMJqaYw5t
m6TMPkRO1zIyeAndQ8PV/TIQVEhTMGuZKJICBxP0rXEQLKOUl09kk3VwDlsCM1yj
ZiVcmZI7/Hyk2U6c0NGUUmpTSNQBraA8ZJ8tJJ28WTM1S4ogBpBjn3DP+hPlZI7h
Ek0gCc6XfwChOcRBY1kd3IHuC3fI51so+5ohcdILCflhODmAQZapNIP5dJudX3sd
6WWi/ibgQycJ+43Nricn0JxVDRzdOViJo2ZuA0Bte0wihVwoYw==
Private-Lines: 14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Private-MAC: d44d6ad6590c05c04eb78770be16ee5e11f0802e
```

Comment: Your key is just wrong. If I put your key string to a file and try to load it using any key tools (PuTTYgen, ssh-keygen), it just does not work. Contrary, if I generate a new key, your code can load it without any problem.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I did change a few characters of that key so apologies if i broke it.  The key I use works with putty fine. Can you edit my question with a key that works for you so I can try?

Comment: I did not have to add the `u` (i think only in python 2.7) but the key does work.. The KEy I am using was generated with putty.. when I try and pass in the whole file (Not just the private key'. I get a  `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: not a valid RSA private key file`

Comment: Your key works! I have included the `PuTTY` ppk file I use to connect with PuTTY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paramiko supports OpenSSH key format only.

You cannot just take PuTTY format key file and add OpenSSH "headers". This does not make the key be in OpenSSH format.

Use PuTTYgen to convert the PuTTY key to OpenSSH key (*Conversions > Export OpenSSH key*).